# How to reference to optimization problem which is defined by optidef package

Tags: xepersian

Hi

I'm new in tex and  I'm using `optidef` and `xepersian` packages in latex.

There is a problem , I can not reference to my optimization problem .

I wrote this simple code  :

```
\begin{argmini}
%\label{cvx_ineq}
{\hat{x}}{S_2(\hat{x})}
{}{}
\addConstraint{||\hat{x}_\mathcal{M}-x_\mathcal{M}||_2^2}{\leq \epsilon^2 }
\end{argmini}
```

As you can see I commented the label line. (if you uncomment it you'll get an error!).

Is there any way for labeling optimization equations?

Because there was no tag named `optidef` I just taged `xepersian`

I would appreciate for your solutions.

Comment: Your label line has a typo: correctly it is `\label`, while you wrote `\lable`. If you still have any problem, please, add a complete minimal working example.

Comment: sorry i corrected that line ,but the problem is same as the previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can label it:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{argmini}
{\hat{x}}{S_2(\hat{x})}
{\label{opt:cvx_ineq}}{}
\addConstraint{||\hat{x}_\mathcal{M}-x_\mathcal{M}||_2^2}{\leq \epsilon^2 }
\end{argmini}

\ref{opt:cvx_ineq}
\end{document}
```

You put the `\label` in between the `\begin{argmini}` and its required arguments. That's what was causing the problem.